# Referencing column 'build_id' and referenced column 'build_id' in foreign key constraint 'screenshot_ibfk_1' are incompatible

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to add foreign key constraint to build_id in screenshot table and used this command

```
ALTER TABLE screenshot ADD FOREIGN KEY (build_id) REFERENCES build(build_id);
```

Schema for build table:

```
CREATE TABLE `build` (
  `build_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `project_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `baseline` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `status_ind` enum('created','passed','failed','inactive','archived') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'created',
  `create_timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `update_timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `created_by` varchar(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (`build_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `build_unique_index` (`name`,`project_id`),
  KEY `project_id` (`project_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `build_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`project_id`) REFERENCES `project` (`project_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3
```

Schema for screenshot table

```
 CREATE TABLE `screenshot` (
  `screenshot_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `screenshot_config_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `test_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cloud_link` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `create_timestamp` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `update_timestamp` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `status` enum('active','inactive','deleted') DEFAULT NULL,
  `viewport` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `browser` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `os` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `deviceName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `build_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `build_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem was that build is utfmb3 and screenshot is utf8mb4, that is incompatible

Change the character set to something compatible or ideally the same

> ```
> CREATE TABLE `build` (
>   `build_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
>   `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
>   `project_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
>   `baseline` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
>   `status_ind` enum('created','passed','failed','inactive','archived') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'created',
>   `create_timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
>   `update_timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
>   `created_by` varchar(255),
>   PRIMARY KEY (`build_id`),
>   UNIQUE KEY `build_unique_index` (`name`,`project_id`),
>   KEY `project_id` (`project_id`)#,
>   #CONSTRAINT `build_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`project_id`) REFERENCES `project` (`project_id`)
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
> ```

> ```
>  CREATE TABLE `screenshot` (
>   `screenshot_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
>   `screenshot_config_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
>   `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
>   `test_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
>   `cloud_link` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
>   `create_timestamp` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
>   `update_timestamp` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
>   `status` enum('active','inactive','deleted') DEFAULT NULL,
>   `viewport` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
>   `browser` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
>   `os` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
>   `deviceName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
>   `build_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
>   `build_id` varchar(255)  DEFAULT NULL
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
> ```

> ```
> ALTER TABLE screenshot ADD FOREIGN KEY (build_id) REFERENCES build(build_id);
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=07e4428d7debc34c6e31042df6343bd0)*